# Check if cookie has expired, if yes logout the user

Tags: jquery, cookies

I noticed that when your "session" on facebook has expired there appears a popup saying that you will be logged out, how can i check periodically if the cookie has expired?
I tried with this:

```
    setInterval(function() {
    if($.cookie('id') == null) {
        location.reload;
    }
},60000);
```

UPDATE: Sorry I noticed that I didn't say that I want to update the "status" with a mysql query with ajax. That's not a problem, but if I want to do this, I need the ID set in the cookie, but if that's expired I cannot do that :/, do I need to set another cookie with a long date expiration when the user logs in?

Comment: you `tried with this` ...and? :)

Comment: Can FB cookies be accessed by javascript? That sounds like a bad idea (wouldn't surprise me though)

Comment: Sorry I noticed that I didn't say that I want to update the "status" with a mysql query with ajax. That's not a problem, but if I want to do this, I need the ID set in the cookie, but if that's expired I cannot do that :/, do I need to set another cookie with a long date expiration when the user logs in?

Comment: @Denn ok now I understand! You should update your question to make it clear :)

Comment: ...and I will assume that somehow the cross-domain issues of accessing a cookie from a different domain are solved. Are you writing an extension, or a bookmarklet, or sort of? Maybe this can be useful: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4701922/how-does-facebook-set-cross-domain-cookies-for-iframes-on-canvas-pages

Comment: the link @Stefano gave does explain a concept, more or less the answer itself, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Using only cookies to keep track of whether a user is logged in is a security risk. It is best to use a combination of cookies/server-side sessions. Most frameworks/CMSs utilize this structure. Since facebook is constantly communicating with the user, most likely each time an AJAX call is made it is looking for something in the response indicating an invalidated session.

If you are using sessions you will need to maintain some kind of constant communication with the server in order to achieve this.

```
var check = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        url : '/authorize/ajax/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            if(data.unauthorized) 
                window.location.href="/login/";
            }
        }
    } );

},5000);
```